# Sql Server Full Text : searching for umlaut-accented text

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, diacritics

We have a working full text search using our Sql Server database. It's all running smoothly but we found a special case with which full text search refuses to work: Sql Server will not find umlaut-accented words within a French indexed column. Let's says I have an indexed table and I want to look for the word "maïs":

```
-- Finds matches, as expected
select * from Table where MyText like '%maïs%'

-- No matches (there should be)
select * from Table where CONTAINS(MyText, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "maïs")', LANGUAGE 1036) 

 -- Finds matches, as expected (so we can say other accent types works)
select * from Table where CONTAINS(MyText, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "tête")', LANGUAGE 1036)
```

I reviewed the technical details of the database and indexes but nothing seemed really out of place (all columns has the correct French indexing language, collation is French_CI_AS), and as I said other queries on that index are fine.

So if anyone has a suggestion to make this particular case work, I'd be interested :)

Thanks

Comment: What is the catalog's `ACCENT_SENSITIVITY` set to?

Comment: @Keith It's set to `OFF`